# How to encrypt/decrypt in Javascript with DES?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, des

I see encoding function on Java back-end and I need to write same functionality on NestJS (NodeJS). The result of these transformations is something like so C6EB48123226CDBB3A5048FE6A92CA06, I see it in a database table.

So, I tried to use cripto-js library, it works with DES encryption but I couldn't get result that looks like C6EB48123226CDBB3A5048FE6A92CA06.

As instance (works fine):

```js
var encrypted = CryptoJS.DES.encrypt("DataFromInput", "secretKey");​
var decrypted = CryptoJS.DES.decrypt(encrypted, "secretKey");
```

But my question still is open. I don't have any idea that I have to do for getting string similar to C6EB48123226CDBB3A5048FE6A92CA06, because I don't understand that Java code below does and how I can implement it in Javascript.

I need some step-by-step instruction like: Encrypt string -> Take property X from result -> Transform it to array -> Get hash of array etc.

```java
public static String getEncrypted( String str, String key )
{
    try
    {
        KeySpec keySpec = new DESKeySpec( key.getBytes( Charset.forName( "UTF-8")));
        SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance( "DES");
        SecretKey desKey = keyFactory.generateSecret( keySpec);

        try ( ByteArrayOutputStream cipheredBaos = new ByteArrayOutputStream() )
        {
            Cipher desCipher = Cipher.getInstance( "DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
            desCipher.init( Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, desKey);

            CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream( cipheredBaos, desCipher);
            cos.write( str.getBytes( "UTF-8"));
            cos.close( );
            
            return DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary( cipheredBaos.toByteArray( ));
        }
    }
    catch ( Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why in this day and age are you even using DES? It is has been considered insecure for decades already.

Comment: As I mentioned, I have too old backend on Java :-)

Comment: DES was already considered insecure when Java was still in its infancy though.

Comment: At least I can see you miss some args in the encrypt method. For example: `var encrypted = CryptoJS.DES.encrypt(message, keyHex, {
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
});` I didn't test it.

Comment: You've to import the key with the UTF-8 encoder, e.g. `CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("01234567")`, since CryptoJS uses a key derivation function when the key is passed *directly* as string. The hex encoded ciphertext results with `encrypted.ciphertext.toString()`. Also, as mentioned in the previous comment, ECB must be set (since CBC is the default). Besides DES, ECB is also insecure.

Comment: @Topaco, his advice is solution. Thanks a lot.